# How do I link two running docker containers together?

Tags: docker

I'm wondering how to link docker containers that are already running.  Is this possible?

For example if I have 2 app (`app1` and `app2`) images and a single running `mongo` container, I can link them pretty easily when I `run` the them by doing the following:

```
docker run -d -name app1 --link mongo:mongo -p 8080:8080 app1
docker run -d -name app2 --link mongo:mongo -p 8081:8081 app2
```

This works great.  However, suppose I have already ran `app1` and `app2` *without* linking them to the mongo container at the start, how do I go about linking the applications' containers to the running mongo container?

Comment: On the default network or a user defined network?

Comment: I think we can't. But if you use ```docker-compose```, you don't need the ```--link``` anymore.

Comment: see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3155 at the end you see `Create a network using docker network create $NETWORK_NAME
    Create your containers using docker create --net $NETWORK_NAME

You can then refer to containers sharing the same network by their hostname (either the --name you passed in to create/run, or docker inspect --format '{{.Config.Hostname}}' $CONTAINER_ID).`

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose port from your container to host, then container can ping each other via your HOST_IP (from inside container- default is 172.0.0.1).

Example: your `app` is running on 8080 and your `mongo` is running on 8000 (exposed port to host)
exec inside your app container and get $HOST_IP using `ifconfig`

After that, try to ping to your mongo service

```
curl $HOST_IP:8000 (I'm not sure about this command ^^ if it's not ok, google it)
```